# How to initialize jCarousel jQuery plugin for multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I have several id that has the following name test1, test2, test3, test4 and I have the following jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#test').jcarousel({
                //something
            });
        });
```

I have the following code as well:

```
jQuery.get(
                'allmovieloader.php',
                {
                    first: carousel.first,
                    last: carousel.last
                                    id: myelementid
                },
                function(xml) {
                    mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, carousel.first, carousel.last, xml);
                },
                'xml'
            );
```

So when I call get I want to pass in the id as well, as test1, test2, test3
How should I change this jQuery code so that it works for test1, test2, test3

Comment: Why not assign a class to all of them?

Comment: cant you select this by class $('.test') where test is a class defined on all the item selected for jcarousel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be far easier to assign a class-name to the various elements, and then use the class as the selector (`$('.className').jcarousel({ // something })`), but if you want to use `id`s as the selector you've got a couple of choices:

First:

```
$('#test1, #test2, #test3').jcarousel({ // something });
```

Secondly:

```
$('div[id^="test"]').jcarousel({ // something });
```

---

Based on your comment to [@Bjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531618/jquery-noob-question/5531636#5531636):

> I need to use id as each id name will be passed in as a parameter

You could still use the class-name as the selector:

```
$('.className').jcarousel(
    function(){
        var idOfElement = this.id;
        // other stuff
    });
```

> a side question, how can jQuery get the element name so I can pass it to get?

To get the element name (I'm assuming you mean tag-name?) you can use:

```
$('.className').jcarousel(
    function(){
        var nameOfTag = this.tagName;
        alert(nameOfTag);
     });
```

References:

- [attribute-starts-with (`^=`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: a side question, how can jQuery get the element name so I can pass it to get?

Comment: I like the regular expression solution.. that's what I was looking for

Comment: @EquinoX: feel free to up-vote, or accept, if the posted answer helped/solved your problem. :)

Comment: I actually tried that this.tagName and it didn't work.. I want to use it to pass in the get

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your selector? I.e. `#test, #test1, #test2` etc.? Or better, assign a class.

Comment: I need to use id as each id name will be passed in as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest selecting the elements you want and then "iterate" through each of them using $().each, which applies a passed function to every element you've selected. You can get the specific properties of each element that way.

```
$('#test, #test1, #test2').each(function(index, dom_element){
 var $this = $(dom_element);
 var id = $this.attr('id'); //eg. test, or test1, or test2
 $this.jcarousel({/*do something*/});
});
```

var $this is made because then the selector only has to be processed once. You could use $(this) instead, but I think it would be a tad bit slower.